# Como funcionam os sinônimos de tags?

Tags: suporte, tags, tags-sinônimas

Há no site duas tags que deveriam ser sinônimos: a tag [unity](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) e a tag [unity-3d](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-3d). Eu já havia pensado em fazer essa sugestão há algum tempo, mas pela falta de oportunidade só consegui tentar isso hoje (e não consegui sequer sugerir).

Eu admito que me esqueci que a ideia do sinônimo é justamente facilitar pra não se ter que fazer a remarcação manualmente, então como eram poucas (4 ou 5) perguntas com a tag [unity](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) eu troquei em todas elas para a tag [unity-3d](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-3d) (porque essa tag já tinha mais perguntas e porque o nome da ferramenta é, de fato, Unity 3D). Só que ao tentar sugerir que a tag [unity](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) é sinônimo da tag [unity-3d](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-3d) (fui na última sugerir a primeira como sinônimo), ocorre o seguinte "erro":

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Bom, a tag certamente existe no sistema (uma vez que já teve perguntas e até tem um fragmento que alguém colocou lá). Será que o erro se deve a não haver (mais) perguntas com ela? Se for esse o caso, e agora? Como eu "resolveria" isso? :)

**Edit**: Fiz um teste [como sugerido pelo @bigown](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4913/como-funcionam-os-sin%C3%B4nimos-de-tags#comment17553_4913) (adicionando novamente a tag [unity](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) a uma pergunta qualquer). E o erro muda para esse:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Acredito que tem que ter pelo menos 1 pergunta com ela, talvez até mais. Eu descobri que o sistema apaga *tags* pouco usadas em determinadas circunstâncias. Não sei bem o critério. Mas neste caso é fácil perceber que a *tag* não está sendo considerada como ativa. A mensagem certamente não ajuda entender o real motivo. Ponha de volta em uma pergunta e teste :)

Comment: @bigown Sério? Eu achei que era alguma burrada minha. Vou fazer o teste depois. De todas as formas, se for isso mesmo, esse tipo de problema/dificuldade já não deveria ter sido descoberto (ou relatado) antes?

Comment: @bigown Bom, fiz o teste, e agora o erro mudou para: "Falha ao propor sinônimo: Os sinônimos específicos da versão só podem ser criados por moderadores". :/ #bummer

Comment: O problema foi resolvido :)

Comment: @bigown Heim? Como assim?

Comment: O problema descrito não existe mais, porém agora tem que passar para os moderadores fazer o que deseja.

Comment: @bigown Hum... Parece que foi uma tentativa de humor sua que eu não entendi, né? rs Desculpe. Ainda assim, bizarro... Qual seria o propósito de uma opção para sugerir sinônimos que não permite ser utilizada? :)

Comment: É isso :) Permite, mas tem restrições. Esse deve ser uma caso por ser muito parecido. Um `oop` e `orientação-a-objeto` não causaria problemas, assim como `c#` e `csharp` (acho :P).

Comment: @bigown Mas então o sistema tá errado. Porque a ideia de "sugerir" é justamente facilitar a vida de todos. Se as pessoas precisarem abrir postagens no Meta ou entrar em contato diretamente com um moderador toda vez que não conseguirem sugerir sinonímeas simplesmente porque os termos são muito parecidos, a função não apenas deixa de ser útil nesses casos como vai atrapalhar ativamente.

Comment: É. Mas é melhor eu não falar mais nada sobre sistema errado :)

Comment: @bfavaretto, é isso mesmo? Eu não consigo sugerir tal sinônimo só porque são muito parecidos?

Comment: @Gabe vc consegue ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O sistema não estava lhe permitindo fazer a sugestão de criação de sinônimos pois ele estava interpretando como se a tag `unity-3d` fosse uma determinada versão derivada da tag `unity`.

Um caso similar é a tag [python-3.x](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), que não faria sentido sugerí-la como um sinônimo da tag [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), já que as vezes é importante especificar na pergunta uma versão específica.

O sistema impede sugestões assim por considerar necessário uma atenção em especial para ela, e ao pararmos para analisar bem concluímos (eu, você e o Gabe, no chat) que o melhor mesmo era que tirássemos o hífen da tag deixando [unity3d](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d).

Eu acabei criando o sinônimo antes de fazer essa mudança, mas se a tag estivesse sem o hífen desde o princípio você teria criado sua sugestão de sinônimo sem problemas.

Comment: Mais uma vez, muito obrigado pela ajuda @Math! :)